# How to decide what to put in asp mvc areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to make a good architecture for my asp.net mvc application.
Since this is the first time I structure something real with asp.net mvc I need some advices.

> +Areas  {Account  Admin  Module1  Module2}

1) In the account I have planned to put login page where users
will be redirected if they are not authenticated. Is it ok
to put login page here or it should be somewhere else?

2) Just for example. If you need to separate facebook in areas
can you provide short list of areas that would be there? I ask
this because facebook has menu sections and I need to understand
when something should be moved in separate area. Would it be: account, admin, friends, statuses, groups, events, navigation bar etc, areas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to create areas for the parts that are easily separatable and could be reused in my other projects.

Classic example could be a guestbook or forum (if you have your own forum engine) or plugins for voting and stuff like that.

Comment: Ok. If I have one page which contains from a few section: friends list, task list, status list of friends, personal data... Should every this section be in separate area?
And one more thing if I separate project in different areas, then should I put something in project root controller/view/model folders?